# Having trouble with YAML and the Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, yaml

Could someone help me with this (I'm new to YAML):

```
application: baking-tutorial
version: secureable
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /robots\.txt
static_files: static/robots.txt
upload: static/robots\.txt

- url: /static
static_dir: static
secure: optional

- url: /main\.html
mime_type: text/html
static_files: static/\1
upload: static/main\.html

- url: /static/.*
 script: mirror.app
 secure: optional

- url: /.*
script: mirror2.app
secure: optional
```

Basically I'm trying to host a password protected site so I have the mirror2.app directing you to it then if you get it right the JavaScript redirects you to the main.html except it's not there.

Comment: btw the password part works just the main.html doesn't appear and it works on my computer just not if I run it in the engine

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not a correct YAML file. You have to take care to properly indent everything at the same level that belongs together:

```
application: baking-tutorial
version: secureable
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /robots\.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots\.txt

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  secure: optional

- url: /main\.html
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/main\.html

- url: /static/.*
  script: mirror.app
  secure: optional

- url: /.*
  script: mirror2.app
  secure: optional
```

the value for the mapping key 'handlers' is a list of mappings. Each of those latter mappings has at least a 'url' key and then some others.

In YAML, if you outdent to a previous level, you essentially end the previous construct (sequence, mapping). Also note that the `-` for the list items in a mapping value can align with the key (the don't have to, they can be more indented, as long as they all are indented the same level).

Comment: No I just found the issue. A random slash in my html and a bit of weird code (was working on it pretty late last night) and it works!